# Excel Data Validation list of concrete percentages not working - bug?

Tags: excel, validation, percentage

I have a cell that needs to hold a user-editable percentage, but it may only contain a multiple of 10% in the range 0%-100%.

My logical solution was to just apply data validation on the cell, and specify it as "List", with the list being "0%,10%,...,100%".  This way the users can both type in the number as well as select it from the in-cell drop down list.

However, when I consecutively save & close the workbook and then re-open it again, only the drop down entry works.  All attempts to manually enter a percentage lead to Excel disallowing it; it just doesn't recognize the input as valid anymore.  Changing the data validation definition a bit and back again makes it all work as expected, but only up to the next re-open of the workbook.

A workaround I found is to specify the valid percentages in a named cell range, and refer to that range in the validation rule; this keeps working even across re-opens of the workbook.

I wonder though if this is truly an Excel 2010 bug, or if it's something particular to my Excel installation?  If anyone could test this (especially on other Excel versions), I'd be very grateful.

The steps to reproduce it:

1. Start a new workbook
2. Select cell A1 and format it as a percentage
3. Apply data validation, and
4. Set 'allow' to "List"
5. Set 'source' to "0%,10%,20%" (without the quotes)
6. Keep 'ignore blanks' and 'in-cell dropdown' checked
7. Verify you can both manually and via the drop-drown list enter one of these choices (you can enter it either as 10% and 0.1)
8. Save the workbook, close it, and re-open it
9. Try to enter another percentage, both via the drop-down list and manual entry

Result: manual entry triggers the data validation error prompt...

If this is a genuine bug, I'll post the above mentioned solution as a proper solution.  If you have a better one, that is of course welcome as well!

## Addition

The workaround I found comes down to:

1. In the cells C1 to C3 enter the values 0%, 10% and 20% respectively.
2. Select the range C1 to C3, and name it e.g. "allowedPercentages"
3. In the data validation for cell A1, set the 'source' to "=allowedPercentages" (without the quotes)

Comment: It looks like a bug for me (tried with Excel 2010). Although, I would simply not put a data validation like 0,2 without the percentage format and it would work. But this "bug" or "feature" is described here - http://excelexperts.com/Excel-Tips-Data-Validation-for-percentages

Comment: I tried this in Excel 2013 exactly how you set it up, and it worked fine for me.  No issues.  So if it is a bug in 2010 they fixed it in 2013.

Comment: @Vityata: true, setting a range between 0 and 1 could be a solution, but then you'd lose the requirement of "only multiples of 10%"...

Comment: @CarlColijn - what happens if you refer to a list explicitly? And on this list you have `0,1;0,2;0,3`?

Comment: @Vityata: I suppose you mean to put the allowed values in a range of cells, give that range a name, and then use that name as the validation source? That does indeed work (with my Excel 2010 version at least).  It's the workaround I hinted at in the Q; I'll update it to make it more clear on what I meant there.

Comment: I've managed to get this tested on an EN-US version of Excel 2007: the bug is also there.  An NL-NL version of Excel 2003 however works correctly; seems this bug was only present in the 2007 and 2010 versions (unless something else like e.g. the Office install language also has something to do with it, but I doubt that).